# How could I rewrite urls properly?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have URLs like http://url.com/top_admin/order.php?do=view&oid=124 and
I need to rewrite it to http://url.com/top_admin/order/view/124 , where
top_admin is a folder that contains my script.
this is my code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on                                          
RewriteRule ^order/(.*)/([0-9]+) order.php?do=$1&oid=$2 [L]
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(top_admin/order)\.php\?do=([^&]*)&oid=(\d+)\s [NC]
##Rule for external rewrite with 301.
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]
##Rule for internal rewrite to .php file.
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ $1.php?do=$2&oid=$3 [L]
```